# Error "Column Index out of range, 0 < 1" when executing "SHOW PROFILES"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can I execute the query "SHOW PROFILES" over jdbc?

I tried something like:

```
try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW PROFILES;");) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(0));

    }
}
```

But I am getting an exception as `"Column Index out of range, 0 < 1. error "`.

Comment: [Right from the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29) "**the first column is 1, the second is 2,**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is clearly saying that Column Index should be start with one.

Try changing `rs.getString(0);` to `rs.getString(1);`

see this question for more info;
[java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442194/java-sql-sqlexception-column-index-out-of-range-0-1)

Comment: yep I guess I was kind of expecting It won't work so I did not really exam the error msg! It works!